# Express validator iteration to body check every item in the array has the correct input

Tags: node.js, validation, express, express-validator

Good night. I have to validate if every element in the array has a username. I'am currently using express-validator successfuly to validate only one user, but I dont know how to deal with the array.

I want to do somethink like

```
  req.checkBody('username', 'username is required').isEmail();
```

But for each element in the array. In which case the following input sends an error for the first argument in the array given that it has no username. I was thinking something like

```
  req.checkBody('req.body[1].username', 'username is required').isEmail();
```

whould work but it dosn't.

```
[{
  "password": "123",
  "nombre":"kila",

},
{
  "username": "vanilla@skalia.com",
  "password": "123",
}]
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do it this way -

```
for(let i = 0; i < req.body.length; i++) {
    req.checkBody([i, 'username'], 'username is required').isEmail();
}
```

This will validate all the objects in the array to have a `username` field again the `isEmail` check.